# How to open a qml interface using systemd?

Tags: qt, c++11, qml, systemd

I want to open a qml interface using systemd and when the user closes the window, the system automatically restarts the process to open the window again, but the interface doesn't open.

I tried this configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=test
After=graphical.target
Wants=graphical.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=~/test
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=test.Service
```

test is my binary, that runs my qml interface.

How can I do this?

Please if possible provide an example for my case.